# How to understand variational principles and the math underlying them?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, boundary-conditions, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I work in finance, and studied math in college. I'm trying to use QFT statistics to model some aspects of the market. (I've already made some progress by deriving the Black-Karasinski Hamiltonian for spot interest rates.) To this end, I am reviewing classical field theory, and I don't understand variational principles very well. I apologize if this question has already been asked (I searched for it, but couldn't find an answer), and if I have violated the communities guidelines I'd be more than happy to edit my question.

Define a field $\varphi$ on spacetime $x,t$. The Lagrangian density and action are given by
$$
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\widetilde{m}\left(\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t}\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}\widetilde{m}\left(\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\vec{x}}\right)^2-V(\varphi)
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{S}=\int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt\int_{\mathcal{R}^3}d^3x\,\mathcal{L}(t,x)=:\int_V\mathcal{L}(\varphi,\partial_\mu(\varphi)),
$$
where $V=\mathcal{R}^3\otimes[t_i,t_f]$.

From here I would like to derive the classical field equation, but this involves variational principles, and I'm struggling to understand.

A transformation for the scalar field, keeping the spacetime manifold fixed, has the form $\varphi(x)\mapsto\varphi^\prime(x)=\varphi(x)$ and leads to the variation $\delta\varphi:=\varphi^\prime(x)-\varphi(x)$.

Question 1: Shouldn't this always be zero by the previous equality?

With the constraint that the variation at the initial and final surface is zero, i.e.
$\delta\varphi|_{t=t_i}=0=\delta\varphi|_{t=t_f}$, the variation of the action is given by
\begin{align*}
\delta\mathcal{S}
&=\int_V\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\varphi(t,x)}\delta\varphi(t,x)+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\varphi}\delta\partial_\mu\varphi\right)\\
&=\int_V\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\varphi(t,x)}-\partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\varphi}\right)\delta\varphi(t,x)+\int_V\left(\partial_\mu\left(\delta\varphi\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\varphi}\right)\right)\\
&=\delta\mathcal{S}_V+\delta\mathcal{S}_{\partial V}.
\end{align*}

Question 2: How is this last term identified as the "variation on the boundary"?

The constraint that the variation on the boundary be zero yields $\delta\mathcal{S}_{\partial V}=0$. That the variation must equal zero, i.e., that $\delta\mathcal{S}=\delta\mathcal{S}_V=0$, implies
$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\varphi}-\partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\varphi)}=0.
$$
This is the classical field equation.

Question 3: The way I'm thinking about variation is that we slightly perturb the way the field $\varphi$ evolves between $t_i$ and $t_f$, while asserting that the perturbed field's evolution must start and end in the same was as $\varphi$. The assertation that the variation is zero means that the action $\mathcal{S}$ is stationary with respect to infinitesimal changes in the evolution. If this is correct, why does the math for $\delta\mathcal{S}$ work out as above, i.e., is there an explicit mathematical definition for this $\delta$?

Comment: You should look up a good textbook on the calculus of variations. All of your questions are treated well in them.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: For question 1, $\varphi(x)\rightarrow \varphi'(x)=\varphi(x)$ does indeed look incorrect to me, for the reason you say. If there's variation in the *field*, then I'd expect that equation to look like $\varphi(x)\rightarrow \varphi'(x)=\varphi(x)+\epsilon(x)$. If there's a *change in coordinates* from $x$ to $x'$, then the equation for a scalar would be $\varphi(x)\rightarrow \varphi'(x')=\varphi(x)$; however, this is different than what you wrote because your argument of $\varphi'$ is $x$ not $x'$. Is it possible your resource was doing a change in coordinates, and you swapped $x'$ with $x$?

Comment: There are plenty of good textbooks covering calculus of variations. So much so that I have a criteria to choose between good texts. Treatments that bring calculus of variations closest to single variable calculus by setting $\phi(x)\to\phi(x)+\varepsilon\eta(x)$ where we only differentiate by the scalar $\varepsilon$, tends to be most clear. The Mathematical Methods textbook by Riley, Hobson and Bence is my go-to suggestion for calculus of variations.

Comment: @Andrew I checked, my reference for these equations does indeed write $\varphi^\prime(x)=\varphi(x)$. But it could also just be wrong, as I've spotted quite a few mistakes from the author so far. I understand the variation much better when discussion general symmetry transformations $x\mapsto\widetilde{x}=\widetilde{x}(t)$, $\phi(x)\mapsto\widetilde{\phi}(\widetilde{x})$, as then the variation just works out to be zero since the Lagrangian is invariant. I don't really know why, but I'm not totally comfortable with the "asserting boundary conditions" in the derivation of the field equation.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Thank you. I also have a book on hand on the calculus of moving surfaces, and I seem to remember there being some calculus of variations thrown in. I'll give both a thorough read.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I haven't looked at the books yet, but I applied Gauss's theorem to $\delta\mathcal{S}_{\partial V}$ as defined above. This yields $$\delta\mathcal{S}_{\partial V}=\int_{\partial V}d\Sigma_\mu\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\varphi)}\delta\varphi+\mathcal{L}\delta x^\mu\right),$$ where $d\Sigma_\mu$ is the vector of the surface element. Is this why it is the variation on the boundary?

Comment: I think your problem is with your conceptualisation. You should learn the basics from the standard examples, which textbooks do, and every question that you have above will have obvious answers. Then you can think properly about everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/807085/2451